# Create a function from another function

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql, ddl

Is it possible to create a new function from another plpgsql function? Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_test()
RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_test2()
  RETURNS INT AS
  BEGIN
  $$
    SELECT 1;
  $$
  END
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I execute the code above I get:

> ```
> ERROR:  unexpected end of function definition at end of input
> LINE 13: $BODY$`
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, totally possible. You just have some random syntax errors.

And I took the freedom to replace the term "stored procedure" in your query with "function", since Postgres does not have stored procedures. Just functions - doing almost, but not quite, the same.

This would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_test()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
BEGIN
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_test2()
     RETURNS INT AS
  $$
    SELECT 1
  $$ LANGUAGE sql;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_test()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$func$
BEGIN

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_test2()
  RETURNS INT AS
$$
BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT 1);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Compare:

- [Can I make a plpgsql function return an integer without using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8169928/939860)

Comment: thanks, It's the first time I know the way to create function in function.  I think your second query has a small problem. When running "select func_test() " , it raises an error: "ERROR:  cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function. LINE 3:    RETURN QUERY" .  If I uncomment "RUN QUERY" clause, the query "select func_test()" works fine but the query "select func_test2()" got an error "ERROR:  query has no destination for result data".

Comment: @lnnnh: Right, either make that `RETURN SETOF ...`or like I fixed it.